# Error when trying to access an item in a for loop

Tags: python-3.x, django

Greetings all I'm trying to get a value if it is equal to a string in looping through items. But I'm getting error "Dictionary entries must contain key/value pairs" and I don't know how to fix that. I'm new to python programming and I'm struggling to find information of how it should be done. I'm using python3.x My code looks like this

```
        for index, debtor in enumerate(case.get_debtors):
        if debtor.type==1:
            context = {
                "recipientName": f"{debtor.first_name} {debtor.middle_name} {debtor.last_name}".replace('None', ''),
                "debtorRole": "Длъжник",
                "debtorAddress": debtorAddress,
                "publicExecutorDefaultBankAccount": "ygvyvb",
                "courtStaff": f"{case_details.systav}".replace('None', ''),
                "courtName": f"{case_details.courtName}".replace('None', ''),
                "archNumber": case.id,
                "debtorName": f"{debtor.first_name} {debtor.middle_name} {debtor.last_name}".replace('None', ''),
                "creditorName": f"{creditor.first_name} {creditor.middle_name} {creditor.last_name}".replace('None', ''), #creditor.type==2
                "creditorAddress": creditorAddress,
                "executionListDate": executionListDate,
                "exListIdentifier": exListIdentifier,
                "amount": amount,
                "amountDate": amountDate,
                "agreementInterest": agreementInterest,
                "penaltyInterest": penaltyInterest,
                "expences": expences,
                "taxPublicExecutor": taxPublicExecutor,
                "brokerage": brokerage,
                "measuresSum": measuresSum,
                if debtor(index).postcode1=="1000":
                    "recipientNameNAP": "ТД НА НАП – СОФИЯ",
                    "recipientAddressNAP": "Адрес: ул.„Аксаков” № 21 1000 София",

                "BASE_DIR": f"{settings.BASE_DIR}".replace("""\\""", "/"),

            }
```

Please help me. I know it is something simple, but I can't find a solution

Comment: Are you sure you can have an `if` statement inside a dictionary initializer? It also looks like your `if` statement just under the `for` loop should be indented one more level.

Comment: I need the if statement because there are variations of the those strings depending of the postcode

Comment: Then calculate the `if` part outside the dictionary initializer and use just the result inside.

Comment: It is not an option, because I have to use the whole context in every if and elif statements. There are 49 variations

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
...
            if debtor(index).postcode1=="1000":
                "recipientNameNAP": "ТД НА НАП – СОФИЯ",
                "recipientAddressNAP": "Адрес: ул.„Аксаков” № 21 1000 София",

...
}
```

The problem is you cannot include an `if` inside the `{ ... }` to initialize a dictionary. You will have to find a different solution to your problem.

One possible solution is to build most of the dictionary as you already do then add an `if` statement afterwords to add any other keys and values to the dictionary.

Comment: can you suggest one?

Comment: @ParantarNakirar Refresh the page to see my edit.

Comment: and how to append the new statement to my context?

Comment: @ParantarNakirar To be clear, you can't append a statement to a dictionary. This doesn't even make sense. Instead, you assign values to keys. Your current `{ ... }` syntax is just a shortcut for assigning a bunch of values to a bunch of keys all at once. If you don't know how to assign a value to a key in a dict, then I suggest you google and read up on it.